# Why does this not show my circle in the window?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw a circle to the jframe but am getting an error. What is wrong with my code?

```
   import java.awt.Graphics;
      import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class Racing {
  public static void main (String[]args) {
 Racing r = new Racing();
r.graphics(null);

}
 public void graphics(Graphics g) {
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.drawOval(480,480,200,200);

 }
 public Racing(){
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Infinite race");
 frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.setSize(960, 960);

}
  }
```

Comment: You're obviously making wild guesses. Don't do that -- read the tutorials. Start here: [Painting with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). Also 1) don't draw in the JFrame itself but instead in a JPanel. 2) Draw in the JPanel's paintComponent method. 3) Search this site for examples of Swing graphics, 4) and the tutorials as I've linked to above. Question closed.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Racing.graphics(Racing.java:12)
 at Racing.main(Racing.java:8)
-im new to coding

Comment: You're getting a NullPointerException, a NPE, because you're passing in a null reference here, `r.graphics(null);` and then within the method trying to call a method off of that null. The tutorials will show you the correct way to do all of this. Luck.